# Working with elements of dataframe in julia

Tags: dataframe, julia

I have a dataframe,

```
df = ( a = 1:0.1:10,
       b = 1:0.2:20
     )
```

I would like to operate on the dataframe elements and find the difference of each element with respect to its previous element in columns `a and b` and store the results in the new columns `da and db`.

## Example

```
a    b    da   db
1    1    Nan  Nan
1.1  1.2  0.1  0.2
.    .    .    .
.    .    .    .
```

Please suggest a solution to this problem.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is another option. Not as efficient as the one above, but showing you what kind of operations you can do in DataFrames.jl:

```
julia> using DataFrames

julia> df = DataFrame(a = 1:0.1:1.5, b = 1:0.2:2.0);

julia> transform!(df, [:a, :b] .=> (x -> [missing; diff(x)]) .=> [:da, :db])
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a        b        da         db        
     │ Float64  Float64  Float64?   Float64?  
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1.0      1.0  missing    missing   
   2 │     1.1      1.2        0.1        0.2
   3 │     1.2      1.4        0.1        0.2
   4 │     1.3      1.6        0.1        0.2
   5 │     1.4      1.8        0.1        0.2
   6 │     1.5      2.0        0.1        0.2
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ShiftedArrays.jl](https://github.com/JuliaArrays/ShiftedArrays.jl) to create lags and then generate the differenced variables:

```
using Pkg
Pkg.add("ShiftedArrays")
using ShiftedArrays
using DataFrames

df = DataFrame(a=rand(10),b=rand(10))
df[:,:d_a]= df[:,:a] .- lag(df[:,:a])
df[:,:d_b]= df[:,:b] .- lag(df[:,:b])
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use `ShiftedArrays` for this:

```
julia> using DataFrames, ShiftedArrays

julia> df = DataFrame(a = 1:0.1:1.5, b = 1:0.2:2.0);

julia> df.da = df.a .- lag(df.a); df.db = df.b .- lag(df.b);

julia> df

julia> df
6×4 DataFrame
 Row │ a        b        da         db        
     │ Float64  Float64  Float64?   Float64?  
─────┼────────────────────────────────────────
   1 │     1.0      1.0  missing    missing   
   2 │     1.1      1.2        0.1        0.2
   3 │     1.2      1.4        0.1        0.2
   4 │     1.3      1.6        0.1        0.2
   5 │     1.4      1.8        0.1        0.2
   6 │     1.5      2.0        0.1        0.2
```

If you want `NaN` instead of missings, you can use `lag(df.a, default = NaN)`.

Note that this also works nicely with grouped data, if you use `combine(groupby(df, :groupvar), :a => lag => :a_L1)` you will only get lagged values within groups.